# How do I break a for-loop in PHP when conditions are met?

Tags: php, loops, primes

I'm diligently plugging away at some code that checks for divisibility (yes, it's to generate primes) and I want to know how to stop a for... loop if the condition is met once. Code like this:

```php
$delete = array();
foreach ( $testarray as $v ) {
    for ( $b = 2; $b < $v; $b++ ) {
        if ( $v % $b == 0 ) {
            $delete []= $v;
        }
    }
```

So `$testarray` is integers 1-100, and the `$delete` array will be filtered against the `$testarray`. Currently though, a number like 12 is being added to `$delete` multiple times because it's divisible by 2, 3, 4, and 6. How can I save my computer's time by skipping ahead when the criteria matched once?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
break; #breaks out of a loop
continue; #skips rest of current iteration
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php